# Retrieving properties of shader storage buffer

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to retrieve some properties of a shader storage buffer:

```
struct A{
   float x;
   float y;
   vec4  v;
};

struct B{
    vec3 u;
};

layout(std430) buffer foo{
   B b;
   A a[];
};
```

Let's suppose the buffer is active. Retrieving the size of the buffer via glGetProgramResourceiv() works and yields 48 machine units. But retrieving the offset of the buffer variables and the array stride of "a" doesn't work.

```
const GLenum props[] = {GL_OFFSET};
GLint* offset = new GLint;
GLuint varIndex = glGetProgramResourceIndex(_progID, GL_BUFFER_VARIABLE, "b");
glGetProgramResourceiv(_progID, GL_BUFFER_VARIABLE, varIndex, 1, props, 1, NULL, offset);
```

The varIndex is always "GL_INVALID_INDEX". How do I get the offsets for all the buffer variables?

Comment: Why do you need to query the offset? You used `std430` layout; the layout is defined explicitly and cannot be changed by the compiler. That's why you picked it.

Comment: I want to get the offsets for didactical reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an invalid index because there *is no* variable `b`. There is `b.u`, but there's no `b`. The only variables that exist, as far as [the introspection API](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Program_Introspection#Naming) is concerned, are variables that are of non-user-defined types.

Structures are just aggregates; the members are the actual values in those aggregates.

Comment: Wow, sometimes it's just tedious to learn OpenGL when such small and coherent informations are scattered to the four winds.
Thank you!

Comment: @Stan: I don't know why you consider it "scattered to the four winds"; it's right there on that page. The same page where it describes the API that you use to query this stuff. Maybe you should read through the Wiki more. It's also clearly specified in the OpenGL specification, again in the same place where it defines the APIs you use to query this stuff.

Comment: I read the specification regarding to the layout type and the wiki articles about the functions above and the interface block. I didn't know that there is this article about "program introspection" and neither there is a link or at least remark on this article in the mentioned wiki articles. The information is there but sometimes it seems I have to search every piece of the puzzle by myself not knowing how many pieces there are.